# Return EventEmitter as Observable in Nest.js

Tags: rxjs, nestjs, eventemitter

`EventEmitter` in **Nestjs** is wrapper around `EventEmitter2` module. I whant that `Server-Sent Events` return Observable with EE.

```js
import { Controller, Post, Body, Sse } from '@nestjs/common';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { EventEmitter2 } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
import { OrdersService } from './orders.service';
import { CreateOrderDto } from './dto/create-order.dto';


@Controller('orders')
export class OrdersController {

  constructor(private ordersService: OrdersService,
              private eventEmitter2: EventEmitter2) {}

  @Post()
  createOrder(@Body() createOrderDto: CreateOrderDto) {
    //  save `Order` in Mongo
    const newOrder = this.ordersService.save(createOrderDto);
    //  emit event with new order
    this.eventEmitter2.emit('order.created', newOrder);
    return newOrder;
  }

  @Sse('newOrders')
  listenToTheNewOrders() {
    //  return Observable from EventEmitter2
    return fromEvent(this.eventEmitter2, 'order.created');
  }

}
```

But after subscribtion to this source from browser i've getting only errors

```js
this.eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/orders/newOrders');
this.eventSource.addEventListener('open', (o) => {
  console.log("The connection has been established.");
});
this.eventSource.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
  console.log("Some erorro has happened");
  console.log(e);
});
this.eventSource.addEventListener('message', (m) => {
  const newOder = JSON.parse(m.data);
  console.log(newOder);
});
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? Are you emitting data in the right format for SSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite likely that you forgot to format the event in the right way.

For SSE to work internally, each chunk needs to be a string of such format: `data: <your_message>\n\n` - whitespaces do matter here. [See MDN reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events)

With Nest.js, [you don't need to create such message manually](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/server-sent-events) - you just need to return a JSON in the right structure.

So in your example:

```js
  @Sse('newOrders')
  listenToTheNewOrders() {
    //  return Observable from EventEmitter2
    return fromEvent(this.eventEmitter2, 'order.created');
  }
```

would have to be adjusted to, for example:

```js
  @Sse('newOrders')
  listenToTheNewOrders() {
    //  return Observable from EventEmitter2
    return fromEvent(this.eventEmitter2, 'order.created')
           .pipe(map((_) => ({ data: { newOrder } })));
  }
```

the structure `{ data: { newOrder } }` is key here. This will be later translated by Nest.js to earlier mentioned `data: ${newOrder}\n\n`

Comment: "Actually, I found a working kludge solution, but yours is more elegant. Thank you.